# Element not Spanning Two Rows in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid layout, and I would like to have one of the grid-items span two rows.

Normally I would do this via with the `grid-row: span 2` property, or by using named grid areas.

In the example though, despite there being room for `.news-item-5` to also span the row below (and effectively take over the space allocated to `.news-item-7`), I can't get this to work.

Is it not possible in this grid layout to have `.news-item-5` span two rows?

As well as the included snippets I have a codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/GzpBmO

**Any help would be amazing.**

```css
/*  ----  GRID */
.second-grid-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 

    "news-1  news-2  news-3"
    "news-1  news-4  news-5"
    "news-6  news-4  news-5";
}

.news-item-1 {grid-area: news-1}
.news-item-4 {grid-area: news-4}
/* .news-item-5 {grid-area: news-5} */

.news-item-7 {
    background: #fff;
}

.news{
    background: lightblue;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<section class="second-grid-wrapper">
  <article class="news news-item-1">
    <div class="top-news-item-text-wrapper">
      <h2 class="news-item-heading td">This is a headline - 1</h2>
      <p class="bottom-text td">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="news news-item-2">
    <div class="top-news-item-text-wrapper">
      <h3 class="news-item-heading td">A SMALLER HEADLINE - 2</h3>
      <a target="_blank" class="bottom-text td">Link</a>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="news news-item-3">
    <div class="top-news-item-text-wrapper">
      <h2 class="news-item-heading td">This is a headline -3</h2>
      <p class="bottom-text td">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="news news-item-4">
    <div class="top-news-item-text-wrapper">
      <h2 class="news-item-heading td">This is a headline - 4</h2>
      <p class="bottom-text td">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="news news-item-5">
    <div class="top-news-item-text-wrapper">
      <h2 class="news-item-heading td">This is a headline - 5</h2>
      <p class="bottom-text td">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="news news-item-6">
    <div class="top-news-item-text-wrapper">
      <h2 class="news-item-heading td">SOMETHING ELSE - 6</h2>
      <p class="bottom-text td">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="news news-item-7">
    <div class="top-news-item-text-wrapper">
      <h2 class="news-item-heading td">This is a headline - 7</h2>
      <p class="bottom-text td">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Solution

Add `grid-auto-rows: 1fr` to your grid container.

```css
/*  ----  GRID */
.second-grid-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr; /* new */  
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "news-1  news-2  news-3"
    "news-1  news-4  news-5"
    "news-6  news-4  news-5";
}

.news-item-1 {grid-area: news-1}
.news-item-4 {grid-area: news-4}
.news-item-5 {grid-area: news-5}
.news-item-7 {background: #fff;}
.news{
    background: lightblue;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<section class="second-grid-wrapper">
  <article class="news news-item-1">
    <div class="top-news-item-text-wrapper">
      <h2 class="news-item-heading td">This is a headline - 1</h2>
      <p class="bottom-text td">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="news news-item-2">
    <div class="top-news-item-text-wrapper">
      <h3 class="news-item-heading td">A SMALLER HEADLINE - 2</h3>
      <a target="_blank" class="bottom-text td">Link</a>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="news news-item-3">
    <div class="top-news-item-text-wrapper">
      <h2 class="news-item-heading td">This is a headline -3</h2>
      <p class="bottom-text td">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="news news-item-4">
    <div class="top-news-item-text-wrapper">
      <h2 class="news-item-heading td">This is a headline - 4</h2>
      <p class="bottom-text td">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="news news-item-5">
    <div class="top-news-item-text-wrapper">
      <h2 class="news-item-heading td">This is a headline - 5</h2>
      <p class="bottom-text td">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="news news-item-6">
    <div class="top-news-item-text-wrapper">
      <h2 class="news-item-heading td">SOMETHING ELSE - 6</h2>
      <p class="bottom-text td">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="news news-item-7">
    <div class="top-news-item-text-wrapper">
      <h2 class="news-item-heading td">This is a headline - 7</h2>
      <p class="bottom-text td">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

---

### Explanation

The element (`.news-item-5`) is actually expanding two rows in your code. Here's the view using [Firefox's Grid outline tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_grid_layouts):

[image]

You can see that the News Item 5 grid item is expanding across two rows. However, its content is confined to the first row.

This is most likely due to an absence of defined row lengths. As a result, [`grid-template-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows) remains at its default setting: `none`, which means all rows will be implicitly created and sized by [`grid-auto-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows), who's default value is `auto`.

*From the spec:*

> [§ 7.2. Explicit Track Sizing: the `grid-template-rows` and
>   `grid-template-columns` properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#track-sizing)
>
> The ***`none`*** value.
>
> Indicates that no explicit grid tracks are created by this property (though explicit grid tracks could still be created by `grid-template-areas`).
>
> > Note: In the absence of an explicit grid any rows/columns will be implicitly generated, and their size will be determined by the `grid-auto-rows` and `grid-auto-columns` properties.

Therefore, as a solution, give the grid some solid guidance by switching from `grid-auto-rows: auto` to `grid-auto-rows: 1fr`.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I understand that now, although I am still a tad confused why it worked on headline-1 and headline-4, but needed the explicit row value for it to work on headline-5

Answer (score -2):

Based on your CSS code, your `grid-template-areas` indicate that you need to adjust the `grid-template-columns:` to read `2fr 2fr 2fr;`. You have your style for `.news-item-5` commented out, so make that visible and comment out the style for `.news-item-7`.
Then move down to your HTML and either remove (or comment out) the `<article class="news news-item-7">` section that you want `.news-item-5` to extend into.

Comment: This works based on the OP's question, so why the downvotes?